# Подскажите пожалуйста jquery работа с масштабированием img, h1-h5,p и другой текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Нормальный метод управления масштабом img, h1-h5,p и другой. Jquery resizable() почему-то не правильно работает с масштабированием (управление мышью размерами) с картинками и текстом, блоки нормально обрабатывает

Comment: Добавьте Ваш код, если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли.

Comment: function resizeid(){
 $('#'+idselected).resizable({
        disabled: false
    });
 
}

function resizeoffid(){
 console.log(idselected);
 
 $('.ui-wrapper').each(function(){ this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML; });
 $('.ui-resizable-handle').each(function(){ this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML; });
 
}